# Excel Help - Modular Dispatch Worksheet

Tags: excel

First question of my career as a "programmer".

Created a spreadsheet which collects data from 7 separate workbooks. The workbooks communicate back and forth as follows.

Master Workbook reports 'Jobs' from it's own column A onto 7 respective workcenters, in their column A, using v-lookup.

Workcenters then report updates in their columns B through E, based upon their progress for the respective job in column A. This data makes its way back to the Master Workbook using a nested if statement and vlookup.

When deleting a 'Job' row from the Master sheet, the job deletes from the Workcenters, but the data tied to the Job remains.  This is causing the Workcenter to populate inaccurate data based upon the Job in Column A.

Hope this isnt too confusing...

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Hi Kyle - How do I link the master worksheet to the workcenter worksheets in such a way that will allow me to delete rows from the master, and thus delete the same row in the workcenters.

Comment: We would need to see what the data actually looks like. it seems like you can just link them so column A (I think anyway based on your description) always match column A in the master workbook.

Comment: This will be tough to explain.  Column's ABC in master control/populate columns ABC on workcenters (done with a vlookup on the workcenters).  Columns DEFGH on workcenters are status inputs forthe respective information in Columns ABC.  Columns DEFGH on workcenters control/ populate back to the Master (these are status updates,done with a combination of a nested if statement and vlookup ).

Comment: When columns ABC are deleted on the master, columns ABC on the workcenters reflect "0", which is fine, BUT columns DEFGH are not deleted and still reflect the status form the previous information.  I need to link Columns DEFGH on the workcenters to columns ABC on the workcenters.

Comment: There's no way to truly delete them without VBA. You could wrap your functions in some sort of iferror to not show zeros, but I think that's as close as you'll come.

Comment: I don't mind zeros.  When I delete columns ABC on the Master, I would like it to reset the entire respective referenced row in the workcenters (Columns A through H) to read "0".

Comment: Are columns A through H lookups to the master? What is happening now when you delete columns A:C on the master?

Comment: Columns A:C are lookups from the master.  Columns D:H report back to the master.  The master has an if statement that pulls the data from each respective worksheet, based on what workcenter the job is currently in. I will post the if staement in the next comment.

Comment: If Staement is too long..

Comment: You can edit your question and include the if statement there. Where do columns D:H on the workcenter sheets pull the data from?

Comment: Columns D:H are manually populated.  Column D has a drop down for moving into the next step, column E has a drop down for % complete, columns F and G have dates, Column H has Notes.

Comment: There's your problem. Without those being formula driven, there is no way for them to show zero, or blank. The only possibility would be to put conditional formatting on to change the text color to match the background color when there is a zero in column A:C. Otherwise, this will require VBA, and it won't be very elegant as you have to open the workbooks to delete rows.

Comment: Was hoping to create something that states "if columns ABC read "0", reset columns D:H".  Can this be done through data validation?